# Can I get a patch-compatible output from git-diff?

Tags: git

I am doing something very simple wrong.  I'm trying to prepare an ordinary patch file, so I can reapply some changes:

```
$ git diff > before
$ git diff something_here > save.patch
$ git checkout . 
$ patch < save.patch
$ git diff > after
$ diff before after
$
```

With `something_here` *blank* it almost works, but the file names aren't right.  I think I'm just I'm missing some option.

In real life, I am going to do a merge after the checkout, so the patch might fail there, but you see what I'm getting at.

**Edit**
My fault here for asking the wrong question.  The actual question is, I want to save my changes away, do a merge, then re-apply the changes, if possible?  I asked it the wrong way because I am *used* to using patch to solve these sorts of problems and `git diff` looked like that's what it wanted me to do.

Charles Bailey's *comment* had the right answer.  For me, git-apply is the right thing to do (git-stash looks more heavy-weight than I need and rebasing and bundles is definitely beyond my current skill level.)  I'm going to accept the answer Charles gave (because you can't accept a comment).  Thanks for all the suggestions.

**Edit, 6 years later**
As anyone familiar with the subject knows, I over-estimated the difficulty of `git stash`.  Pretty much every day or so, I will use the following sequence:

```
$ git stash
$ git merge
$ git stash pop
```

**Edit, 5 years further down the road** I have largely abandoned `git apply` and don’t even used `git stash` much.  `git rebase` FTW.

Comment: Is there any reason you specifically want to use `patch` rather than `git apply` ?

Comment: And even then, do you really need patches rather than something like `git stash` or other git tools?

Comment: Post-edit, I think that `git stash` is the easiest solution for what you are trying to do, but there are lots of approaches that work.

Comment: I haven't tried `stash` but I tried `apply`, and if `stash` is *easier* than that, well, that must be one easy git command.

Comment: @Malvolio: Indeed it is, you don't even have to think of a temporary file name to store your patch in.

Comment: @Charlse, sometimes you need to send a patch to someone without the entire git repository. For example if using `git-svn`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey necromancing this to mention that perhaps I would only like to apply some changes, so editing the patch manually is a quick way to do that.

Comment: @CBBailey, because he might want to create a script that patches downloaded sources, maybe in embedded systems, without git installed.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you want to use patch you need to remove the `a/` `b/` prefixes that git uses by default. You can do this with the `--no-prefix` option (you can also do this with patch's `-p` option):

```
git diff --no-prefix [<other git-diff arguments>]
```

Usually though, it is easier to use straight `git diff` and then use the output to feed to `git apply`.

Most of the time I try to avoid using textual patches. Usually one or more of temporary commits combined with rebase, `git stash` and bundles are easier to manage.

For your use case I think that `stash` is most appropriate.

```
# save uncommitted changes
git stash

# do a merge or some other operation
git merge some-branch

# re-apply changes, removing stash if successful
# (you may be asked to resolve conflicts).
git stash pop
```

Comment: `git diff --no-prefix master > diff.patch` and then `git checkout master` `patch -p0 < diff.patch`

Comment: @Natim For ultimate safety I would recommend using `patch --dry-run < diff.patch` before issuing the last command.

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ what would be the benefit of doing that? Since we are using git we are unlikely to loose anything isn't it?

Comment: @Natim As I said, just for ultimate safety, no need to undo anything in case of error. I was also thinking about people who read this and want to use `patch` outside of git (maybe using a patch file generated by `diff`) in a more general use case.

Comment: In order to include *new* files in your patch you need to *also* include "git diff --no-prefix --cached" in the patch. Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 260):

Just use `-p1`: you will need to use `-p0` in the `--no-prefix` case anyway, so you can just leave out the `--no-prefix` and use `-p1`:

```
$ git diff > save.patch
$ patch -p1 < save.patch

$ git diff --no-prefix > save.patch
$ patch -p0 < save.patch
```

Comment: If you're wondering why, [the man docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#patch-Directories) sums it up nicely - [source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26502/17836).

Comment: This won't work with renames; `git diff` outputs a line which `patch` ignores. `git apply` is the way to go.

Answer (score 16):

The git diffs have an extra path segment prepended to the file paths. You can strip the this entry in the path by specifying -p1 with patch, like so:

```
patch -p1 < save.patch
```

Answer (score 12):

1. I save the diff of the current directory (including uncommitted files) against the current HEAD.
2. Then you can transport the `save.patch` file to wherever (including binary files).
3. On your target machine, apply the patch using `git apply <file>`

> Note: it diff's the currently staged files too.

```
$ git diff --binary --staged HEAD > save.patch
$ git reset --hard
$ <transport it>
$ git apply save.patch
```

Comment: Hahaha.  That's funny. I asked this question almost four years ago and the way I have been doing this has evolved but if you had asked me yesterday how to do it, I would have given your answer and said I got it from answers to this question.  (Actually I would probably use a bare `git diff > save.patch` and `git checkout .` instead of a reset, but yeah...

Comment: Oh didn't notice its 4 yrs old :P. Btw, the reset is just to demonstrate it works.. I also don't see anyone using `git apply` or making the diff relevant to your state and the pointer to the last commit available. Doing just `git diff` hasn't done anything at all

Comment: Yeah, now I wonder how I found out about `git apply`.  The thing with `git diff` is (I think) from using `git reset` -- the relationships among the repo, the index, and the working area are the issue.

Answer (score 8):

A useful trick to avoid creating temporary patch files:

```
git diff | patch -p1 -d [dst-dir]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Also works perfectly with stashes! `git stash show -p stash@{3} | patch -p1 -d [dst-dir]`