# Convert a diff into a commit

Tags: git

I had some unstaged changes in my repo. Output on the terminal:

```
--- a/app/something.java
+++ b/app/something.java
@@ -37,13 +37,17 @@ public class SomeController extends Controller{
                requestVo.setJobName("temp1");
                requestVo.setJobGroup("g1");
                requestVo.setJobInfo(JobInfo.INFO);
-               requestVo.setJobExecutionType(JobExecutionType.IMMEDIATE);
-               requestVo.setExecutionTime(new Date());
+               requestVo.setJobExecutionType(JobExecutionType.TIMED);
+               requestVo.setExecutionTime(getExecutionTime(3600*1000l));
                requestVo.setJobData("testing 123");
        }

+       private Date getExecutionTime(long delay) {
+               return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + delay);
+       }
+

...
```

Then I proceeded to `git reset --hard HEAD`, so I lost my changes. Is there any way to get back the changes? Or apply my changes from the terminal as a commit?

Comment: If you didn't backup your working directory anywhere, and you really did a hard reset to your branch, then your changes may be lost.  Options include falling back on your editor or IDE (e.g. IntelliJ or Sublime Text), which might have saved the previous local version, or making use of some other local backup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* you still have the full output of your `git diff`, as the extract shown in your question suggests, you could try and:

- select and copy-paste this `git diff` output in a file `diff.patch`.
- [apply that patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4610846/6309) on your (reset) sources

That is:

```
git apply save.patch
# or
patch -p1 < save.patch
```

Note: [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) is preferred here, as `git diff` outputs a line for file *renames*, output which `patch` would ignore.

IF you don't have that full diff output... then previous answers/comments apply.

Comment: Excellent answer, just what I was looking for

Comment: What's the preference to use `patch -p1` over `git apply`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Right: I have edited the answer to use `git apply` (which takes care of file renaming)

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard` discards your unstaged work and take your head to the previous commit. After running this command, git have no record of your changes. You have to use some other way but git can't help you here.