# Problem with git flow - pull request merge conflict

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I think my problem is specific. We have following branches in our git development flow: 
`develop` - it's being deployed on test platform, all feature and bugs branches are being merged here and after QA accepts the solution, the feature or bug branch is being merged into 
`stable` branch, which is a base for a release package.

My problem is that I can't merge my accepted feature branch into stable, because JIRA shows merge conflicts on one file... I cannot merge `develop` into my branch because I don't want to have develop in stable. The conflicting file has been changed in other bug/feature branch many days before. I tried to cherry pick this change into my branch, but without success...

What can I do?

@edited

Now I observed that even when I create a fresh branch from stable and change the file, I have merge conflicts when trying to merge with develop!

Comment: Why not fix the merge conflicts?

Comment: At which point did `develop` diverge from `stable`? You can’t test `develop` to work correctly and then push out code from `stable` if it has different code in it. It hasn’t been tested in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot merge develop into my branch because I don't want to have develop in stable.

You could merge it just to reproduce the conflict and resolve it for that one file.

Then [abort the merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919644/6309), but [save the diff for that file (the conflict resolution) is a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4610809/6309) first.

You can then apply that patch to your current feature branch, and merge it to stable.